# How to copy data between 2 snowflake accounts?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Tried searching for snowflake tags on metastack and superuser, and couldn't find them. Hence asking the questions here.

I have 2 snowflake accounts and I need to copy data from production account to testing account. 
How can I do that? I read the snowflake documentation for loading and unloading the data using s3, but is there a quick way to get the data across?

Comment: You should try data sharing feature. There is no data movement. You can directly query data in another account.

Answer (score 0):

As Howard said you could use Data Sharing. Create a share with the data you want to copy, grant the testing account access to the SHARE, create a new database in the testing account from the share. Now you can query that data as if it was in the test account. If you need an actual copy of the data, so you can change it, etc, then you need to do a CTAS from the share to an empty table in another database. This will be much faster than unloading and loading all the data.

Here is the doc to get started: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html